# Azure Function on NodeJS VSCode latest 1.61.0 stopped working

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

Here is my configuration. Worked fine before, after update to latest VSCode, breakpoint unbound.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "smartStep": true,
      "port": 58167,
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you narrow down "not working" a bit? Do the logs say anything? Do you get a response of any kind? What does the code actually do/call out to?

Comment: using azure functions locally, typescript. Breakpoint is unbound, no errors. Breakpoint just not bounding

Comment: was able to figure this out. The issue is that "port" setting is only available for request type "attach" and not "launch" which was working before. 
Here is the documentation link: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging

Thank you Joachin Isaksson for your help

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Yev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17108887/yev) Glad that Issue is resolved and Thanks [joachim-isaksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477878/joachim-isaksson) for your suggestion Posting all these as an answer to help other community members.

The `Port` setting in the below code is available only in `Attach` request type and not for `Launch` request type.

```js
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "smartStep": true,
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"]
    }
}
```

to enable the Auto Attach feature use the below command from the command palette `(ctrl+shift+P)`.

```
Toggle Auto Attach
```

[image]

For complete information check [Node.js debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging).